# Application not getting listed in ipad

Tags: ipad, xcode4.3, ios5.1

We have developed an application. and we are able to access it from the home screen of ipad.But its not getting listed in Settings --> Apps.
Why is it like that.?
Please help us..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you implement a [Settings Bundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)?

Comment: no, actly em very new to iOS develping. Can you help me with it ?

Comment: @Matthias isit mandatory to implement it as so ?

Comment: Actually yes, if you want your settings managed by Settings.app, you have to implement such a bundle. Simply follow the documentation in the link I've provided.

Comment: Then mark the answer I just gave as correct, so I get the reputation. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement a [Setting Bundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html).
Apple provides a [Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH6-SW14) how to  use it for a Settings page.